# Inserting an Image in a specific place using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My html code generated from apex

```
<tr>
  <td class="labelCol">
     <label for="login_page:signup_form:pb2:j_id5:j_id12">Contact Name</label>
  </td>
  <td class="dataCol ">
     <input name="login_page:signup_form:pb2:j_id5:j_id12" value="" type="text">
  </td>
</tr>
```

I want to insert an image between the the two td .

Comment: `insertAfter('.labelCol')` or `insertBefore('.dataCol')`

Comment: WiXXey what have you tried? There are many ways to do this? http://api.jquery.com/prepend/ http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/ http://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: Did you Google? http://google.com/?q=Inserting+an+Image+in+a+specific+place+using+jquery

Comment: Do you want it in another td ? or just in between these two tds ? as between two tds its doesnt display proper in all browsers ?

Comment: yes i want another <td>in between which has been suggested below by eli...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [insertAfter()](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/):

```
$('<td><img src="src.jpg" /></td>').insertAfter("td.labelCol");
```

Comment: I don't think all browsers would display the actual image. Better insert the <img> tag under another <td> tag

Answer (score 0):

Hey Try insertbefore()

```
$('<img src="src.jpg"></img>').insertBefore(".dataCol");
```

Hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you are planning to insert an image between the the two td,

First put a `td` also, as it's a table structure and then add image there.

```
$('<td><img src="img.jpg"></img></td>').insertAfter('.labelCol');
```